# Generating Admin Interfaces in ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a Django-like admin interface generator for ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC?

If not, are there any tools that could assist in creating one?

Comment: What do you mean by admin interface exactly?

Comment: Might be Dynamic Data website you're looking for? else you gotta build it in mvc view (page) by view

Comment: http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-SP1/  has some videos for it

Comment: @çağdaş - good question; when you define the domain model for use in your web application in Django (web framework based on Python), the framework automatically generates web pages that allow an administrator to add/ remove objects etc. I think it is a great idea, because it means you do not have to write all this stuff yourself.

Comment: Um, ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC are two different things...

Comment: Thanks George, rephrased the question. I am interested in both, because I will be doing a data heavy web application in .NET. I personally prefer MVC though because it gives you more control on
the client side. It seems traditional ASP.NET has better support for this kind of thing through Dynamic Data though....

Comment: check out dynamicmvc.com and http://admin.ilaro.net/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ASP.NET Data Dynamics](http://www.asp.net/(S(y3u2uc45kakrr555dijiwvf2))/DynamicData/) may be what you're looking for.

It helps to quickly generate interfaces you can use to manage your data.

Comment: +1. Much appreciated Chris, this may be exactly what im looking for. Will look into it and come back to accept your answer if it is.

Comment: That link is broken. Closest thing I found was this page, but articles are from 2008. https://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-dynamic-data

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing for MVC that I know of.  T4 templating will get you pretty close to this type of automatic interface generation for dummy CRUD pages.  There are lots of freely available templates if you do a bit of searching.

http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx

Comment: Cool. I actually prefer MVC over traditional webforms. I will look into this, though I expect it will still be a lot of work compared to the 'magic' that is performed by Django. Of course I could write it myself and everyone could benefit, but I am afraid I am too lazy :).

Comment: I haven't had the chance to use them myself, but I suspect there are t4 templates available that will get you 80% of the way there. I found Dynamic data to be too rigid for my MVC tastes, but it will probably get you closer to 100% of the way.  Depends on how lazy you are feeling I suppose. :)